# Anaconda Prompt Stuck on "downloading and extracting packages" specifically for Wheel-0.33.4

Tags: anaconda, opencv

I was trying to install opencv following instructions from https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/

It identified some packages that needed to be installed and successfully downloaded three packages (python 3.6.9, pip nad certifi) it then got stuck at downloading wheel-0.33.4 @57Kb(0%). It does not seem to be responding now.

Any advice on how to proceed from here make sure the installation of opencv is complete will help. I'm brand new to the python environment.

Comment: I Ctrl+C'ed out of it and it seemed to work. I finally just did "pip install opencv-contrib-python" on my conda prompt